# Dependency injecting a Model into my Maui Page causes null reference exception, how to fix?

Tags: exception, dependency-injection, maui

I am getting a null reference exception when dependency injecting a Model into my Maui Page. The model is from an outside MVVM Winforms project. The Maui app already has the dependencies added to the project, and intelligence recognizes my references. However I believe my implementation is wrong.
The weird thing to me is if I do not inject the model, the error goes away, but the exception makes it look as if it has to do with the <Entry> element on my Page? "slackmessage" is the name of the <Entry> element.
**Exception:**

> `System.ArgumentNullException`: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'targetObject')'

**Exception Details: & Image Attached HERE** [Exception Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KbEO.png)

```
System.ArgumentNullException
  HResult=0x80004003
  slack=Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'targetObject')
  Source=Microsoft.Maui.Controls
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Setter.Apply(BindableObject target, Boolean fromStyle)
```

```cs
private void InitializeComponent()
{
global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(SlackTesterPage));
slackmessage = global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Entry>(this, "slackmessage");
}
}
```

**Maui Page**

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Billing.Mvvm.Models.Controls;assembly=Billing.Mvvm.Models"
             x:DataType="controls:SlackTesterModel"
             x:Class="Billing.SupportTool.M.App.Pages.SlackTesterPage"
             Title="Slack Tester">
.....
</ContentPage>
```

**Page Codebehind**

```cs
public partial class SlackTesterPage : ContentPage
{
    public SlackTesterModel? SlackTestModel { get; }
    Label slackTesterLabel = new();

    public SlackTesterPage(SlackTesterModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
```

**Outside Project Model Needed:**

```cs
    public sealed class SlackTesterModel : BaseModel, ISupportShown
    {
        private readonly IDriveTrainDashboardApplicationControlRepository _dtConfig;
        private readonly ISmtpMessageClient _smtpClient;

        public SlackTesterModel(
            IDriveTrainDashboardApplicationControlRepository dtConfig,
            ISmtpMessageClient smtpClient
            )
        {
            _dtConfig = dtConfig;
            _smtpClient = smtpClient;

            SendSlackClicked = new RelayCommand(async (val) => await OnSendSlackClicked());
            Shown = new RelayCommand(async (val) => await OnShown());
        }
....
}
```

I have registered services & models, I have the namespaces in the page, and I am trying to use the logic in my page from that model & the services which are dependency injected into that model. This particular model is under a Controls folder in the other project, so Maui is also recognizing it as a control.
**I have also tried this:**

```cs
public partial class SlackTesterPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly SlackTesterModel _slackTestModel;
    Label slackTesterLabel = new();

    public SlackTesterPage(SlackTesterModel slackTestModel)
    {
        _slackTestModel = slackTestModel;
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = slackTestModel;
    }
....
}
```

Comment: If it has to do with the Entry element … why did you not post the declaration of that Entry?

Comment: Could you please show the code which caused this null exception?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in SlackTesterPage constructor, and examine `vm`? Is it null? Is `SlackTesterModel` [registered for dependency injection during app startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection#registration)  (MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp)?